# libsvm not giving support vectors / no support vectors

Tags: machine-learning, regression, svm, libsvm

I am using jlibsvm to do SVM for regression .My data set is very small (42 samples) . When I use the dataset to create the model using epsilon SVR with sigmoid kernel then no support vectors are generated.

This is what I get in my model file :

```
svm_type epsilon_svr
kernel_type sigmoid
gamma 0.02380952425301075
coef0 0.0
label
rho -66.42803
total_sv 0
probA -1.0
SV
```

When I use some other data set on the libsvm website I get a model file with support vectors fine.
Can someone please suggest why no support vectors are being generated for my data set ? 
My data set file is formatted right so no issues there...

Answer (score 1):

This could mean that the best found classification, given your data and the hyperparameters, is to assign the same label to all samples.

- Are your samples unbalanced? What's the number of positive and negative samples? You might want to try to add a weighting to positive/negative samples to account for that
- It could also be the samples are hard to separate given their structure and the kernel type. Have you tried a different structure?

With only 42 data samples, maybe you could add them to your question and get better answers.

Comment: Nicolas thanks for replying.. I used the same data for Neural Networks and K Nearest neighbors it worked fine.I had to adjust a lot of parameters of Neural Network though. My data is non linear and I am using SVM for REGRESSION I used epsilon SVR and tried various kernel functions like - linear,polynomial,radial basis, sigmoid. But same results. Any ideas on as to what parameters to change and try etc ??

Comment: My data has 14 inputs . And number of samples is 42 .. I tried with higher sample 200 . Still didnt help. I am using epsilon SVR .

Comment: @vinzzz, no luck yet? Please add some info if you found out why this happened! thanks!